# Finding the mode of an array: no output

Tags: java, arrays, try-catch, output, mode

I'm writing a program that takes 10 numbers as input and displays the mode of the numbers using parallel arrays and a method that takes an array of numbers as a parameter and returns the value that appears most often in the array. PROBLEM: However, when I run my program it has absolutely no output, also, I am not sure how to implement the parallel arrays. 
Does anyone know? 
Thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class Mode {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
}

public int computeMode(int[] nums) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int maxValue = -1;
    int maxCount = 0;
    int x = 0;
    //count how many times nums[i] appears in array

    System.out.println("Enter 10 numbers: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        try { //try catch exception to catch decimal inputs as well as more /less than 10 integers
            x = scanner.nextInt();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input! Please reenter 10 integer values.");
            scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            i = -1;

            continue;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {
                if (nums[j] == nums[i]) {
                    count++;
                }
            }

            if (count > maxCount) {
                maxValue = nums[i];
                maxCount = count;
                System.out.println("The mode is: " + maxValue);
            }

        }

    }
    return maxValue;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main function is empty, so it does not anything,
and the function doesn't need any parameter, because you read the numbers with the scanner

I think you need this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Mode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        computeMode();
    }

    public static void computeMode(){
        int nums[]=new int[10];
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int maxValue = -1;
        int maxCount = 0;
        int x = 0;
        //count how many times nums[i] appears in array

        System.out.println("Enter 10 numbers: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

            try { //try catch exception to catch decimal inputs as well as more /less than 10 integers
                x = scanner.nextInt();
                nums[i]=x;
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input! Please reenter 10 integer values.");
                i =i -1;
                scanner.nextLine();

                continue;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {
                if (nums[j] == nums[i]) {
                    count++;
                }
            }

            if (count > maxCount) {
                maxValue = nums[i];
                maxCount = count;

            }

        }
    System.out.println("The mode is: " + maxValue);
    }


}
```

Comment: Aha this works, thank you. Do you happen to know if this method uses parallel arrays? And how I would edit the exception to catch only letters or symbols (anything that is not a number as the program simply specifies number...which I assume means either an integer or a decimal). @TurtleLoop

Comment: There is only one array (nums[]), then this method doesn't use parallel arrays. Here you have an example of parallel arrays: http://mathbits.com/MathBits/Java/arrays/ParallelArrays.htm

Answer (score 0):

The code writes `x`, but never reads it; reads `nums`, but never writes it; and implements `computeMode`, but never calls it.